# Output value conflict of signals in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have written a simple vhdl code to enable/disable an output port by some control signals under some conditions. Problem is that the output signal is either U or X while the code looks fine.

The main entity is shown below. the first process is sensitive to `rst` and will disable `oe` when it is 1. The second process is sensitive to `clk` and will enable the `oe` on clock transition. The output value is also set to `5`.

```
entity test2 is
   port( clk: in std_logic;
         rst: in std_logic;
         num: out integer range 0 to 7;
         oe: out std_logic );
end;
architecture behav of test2 is
begin
    process( rst )
    begin
       if rst = '1' then
         oe <= '0';
       end if;
    end process;
    process( clk )
    begin
       if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
         num <= 5;
         oe <= '1';
       end if;
    end process;
end;
```

Now consider the testbench file. As can be seen, in the main process, I set `r` which is connected to `rst` to 1 and then 0.

```
entity test2_tb is
end;
architecture behav of test2_tb is
    component test2 port( clk: in std_logic;
                          rst: in std_logic;
                          num: out integer range 0 to 7;
                          oe: out std_logic );
    end component;
    signal c: std_logic := '0';
    signal r: std_logic;
    signal n: integer range 0 to 7 := 2;
    signal o: std_logic;
begin
    u1: test2 port map( c, r, n, o );
    process( c )
    begin
       c <= not c after 2ns;
    end process;
    process
    begin   
       r <= '1';
       wait for 4 ns;
       r <= '0';
       wait for 8 ns;
    end process;
end;
```

While `r` is 1, the `o` which is connected to `oe` is set to U. Why? Moreover, on the raising edge of the clock, the value of `o` becomes X. Why? please see the waves below

[image]

Comment: You posted a similar question earlier which you deleted that demonstrated the same problem -  two processes driving a signal `we`.  Each process that has a signal assignment has a driver for that signal. The various drivers in an elaborated design network  are resolved into an effective value which is only modified by assignment, a force release if forced or driver disconnection. Having multiple drivers on signals of unresolved types is an error. Both answers recommend the solution, driving signals from a single process. Renaud Pacalet shows a form that is synthesis eligible.

Comment: "...while the code looks fine.", well there's your problem: it doesn't. What you want to create her is described in many examples found online. On forums, tutorials, Xilinx/IntalAltera user guides, etc. By doing some research, you could have probably found your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it short: your `oe` port should probably not be of type `std_logic` but `std_ulogic` (same for `clk` and `rst`) and it should probably be driven by one single process instead of two:

```
process(clk)
begin
  if clk'event and clk = '1' then
    if rst = '1' then
      oe <= '0';
    else
      num <= 5;
      oe <= '1';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Or, if you prefer an asynchronous reset:

```
process(clk, rst)
begin
  if rst = '1' then
    oe <= '0';
  elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
    num <= 5;
    oe <= '1';
  end if;
end process;
```

In case your tools do not support `std_ulogic` properly (unfortunately there are logic synthesizers that do not support `std_ulogic`, at least in the top level), use `std_logic` but be very careful to always drive your output ports (and internal signals) in one single process, except in very specific situations where you really want several pieces of hardware to concurrently drive the same hardware wire, which is quite rare (tri-state logic, high impedance...)

Comment: So the question is why `process(clk,rst)` works while `process(rst)` and `process(clk)` don't!! Both should run concurrent. Isn't that?

Comment: Sorry to insist but you should really have a look at this topic of the SO VHDL documentation.

Comment: I also test that with `ieee.std_logic_1164.all`. With two process it results in U and X. However with `process(rst,clk)` it is ok. The document says for unresolved types, two processes can not drive one signal. I saw that even with resolved types, two processes fail to work.

Comment: The single process as shown in the answer works because there is a single driver.

Comment: @mahmood What you do not understand, I guess, is what happens when  two processes drive the same signal. And also, maybe, that a signal driver does not stop driving just because another one also drives the signal.

Comment: (Retry) "Both should run concurrent" <-- that's the whole problem. _Because_ they run concurrent, they're both competing to drive the signal... which causes a collision of '0' and '1' that resolves to 'X'.

Answer (score 2):

The processes will continue to drive their values even after you made the assignment to oe  (because you never told them to do anything else). One driving 0 an one driving 1 gives an X. Merge the two processes into one with an if-elsif statement. With only one driver there's no conflict. Initially the are both driving U.